# How to pass database value from controller to table popup using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show a popup with data from database. Here I am using AJAX function on `onclick()`. The returned data will show on that popup. Here the popup contain table, so I don't know how to display the data on table.

```
<a href="" class="rqstName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leaveTeacherModal" id="teacher_profile" onclick="profile_view(<?php echo $leave_data->applied_user_id;?>)"><?php echo $leave_data->teacher_name;?></a>
```

**popup**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="leaveTeacherModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog leaveRqstModal-Dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">Leave Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" id="profile_id">
            <div class="leavReqstModalBody">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="lveReqstDetails">
                            <div class="stdntPrflePic">
                                <img src="<? echo base_url();?>application/assets/dist/img/user8-128x128.jpg">
                            </div>

                            <div class="studentDetails">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Robert De Niro</label>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">STD 10 <label> DIV A</label></label>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Class Teacher :</label>
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Sruthi </label>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="lveReqstDesc">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="block2">
                                    <div class="prevREcords">
                                        <div class="box">
                                            <div class="box-header">
                                                <h3 class="box-title">Previous Leave Records</h3>
                                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                            <div class="box-body">
                                                <table id="prevREcords" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Date</th>
                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th class="reason">Reason</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="slectCheckbox">20-Jan - 25-Jan</td>
                                                            <td><a href=""  class="rqstName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leaveRqstModal">Internet
                                                                    Explorer 5.0,</a></td>
                                                            <td>Win 95+</td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="slectCheckbox">20-Jan - 25-Jan</td>
                                                            <td><a href=""  class="rqstName" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#leaveRqstModal">Internet
                                                                    Explorer 5.0,</a></td>
                                                            <td>Win 95+</td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="slectCheckbox">20-Jan - 25-Jan</td>
                                                            <td>Internet
                                                                Explorer 5.5</td>
                                                            <td>Win 95+</td>

                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                    <tfoot>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Select</th>
                                                            <th>Name</th>
                                                            <th>Reason</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tfoot>
                                                </table>
                                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                        </div><!-- /.box -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="prevMonthAttendence">
                            <h5>Previous Month Atteendence</h5>
                            <!--<canvas id="prevMonthAttndnce" width="400" height="400"></canvas>-->

                            <canvas id="prevMonthAttndnce" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="stdntPrfleDetails">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <h4 class="">Applicant Details</h4>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Applicant Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Robert De Niro</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Reason</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">HeadAce</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Applicant Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Robert De Niro</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Reason</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">HeadAce</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Applicant Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Robert De Niro</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Reason</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">HeadAce</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Applicant Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">First Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Attached Documents</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><a href="">Mediacl Certificate</a>,<a href="">Photo</a></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="submitComments">
                                                <div class="widget-area no-padding blank">
                                                    <div class="status-upload">
                                                        <form>
                                                            <textarea placeholder="Remarks" ></textarea>

                                                        </form>
                                                    </div><!-- Status Upload  -->
                                                </div><!-- Widget Area -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Accept</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
function Prev_leave_record()
{
    $teacher_id=$this->input->post('id');
    $teacher_profile=$this->AM->prev_record($teacher_id);
    $out=array('teacher_details'=>$teacher_profile);
    echo json_encode($out);  
}
```

**model**

```
function prev_record($teacher_id)
{
    $this->db->select('teacher_name,applied_user_id,leave_from_date,leave_to_date,leave_short_desc,leave_status');
    $this->db->from('leave_data');
    $this->db->join('ms_teacher','ms_teacher.teacher_id=leave_data.applied_user_id'); 
    $this->db->where('applied_user_id',$teacher_id);
    $teacher_details=$this->db->get();
    return $teacher_details;   
}

<script type="text/javascript">
function profile_view(id3)
{
    //document.getElementById("profile_id").value= id3;
    var a = id3;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "<? echo base_url();?>Attendance/Prev_leave_record",
        data : {"id":id3},
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(res) {
            //var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        }, 
        error : function(res){
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the js fiddle thats explains how to show json data into table

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify([
            {
            id: 1,
            firstName: "Peter",
            lastName: "Jhons"},
        {
            id: 2,
            firstName: "David",
            lastName: "Bowie"}
        ]),
        delay: 3
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // since we are using jQuery, you don't need to parse response
        drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.firstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
}
```

[Link to Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sewm6)